# Translate code that is outside angular with angular-translate

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I have some code in my project that isn't part of my angular application. This code is guised in an ngInclude templates using `<script type="text/x-jquery-tmpl"...` and is essentially just a template that is used dynamically by my angular app.

I want to be able to translate these templates as well. Is there anyway I can call the $translate service with a html template, and some variables to translate and it can return me the translated template as a string, which I can use in my app?

I looked up the api documentation, and couldn't find anything relevant.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you may load your translatable template via Ajax and get the raw response. This response should be a string with de document content.

After that, you just need to translate this string and inject it in your doc as a `script type="text/ng-template"`.

It should look like this:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="bar.html">
  // your content should be injected here
</script>
```

Now, you just need to call it as a regular template for your route, pointing the route to `bar.html`.

Something like

```
$routeProvider.
  when("/foo",{ controller: "MyController", templateUrl: "bar.html"});
```

Another way is creating a directive to do that job for you. Maybe extend the `<script type="text/ng-template"` directive allowing it to receive the translatable doc url and translating it.

Something like:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="foo.html" doc-url="translatableDoc.html" attr-language="English" />
```

Comment: The template in questions isn't formatted as an angular template. So I am not sure this approach would work :-/

Comment: As you are translating a string, the format does not matter. For the js it is still being a string. If you need to translate only some parts of the doc, you can use a regex to find and replace what and where you want.